# OneDrive has half loading icon (?) near folder name

Tags: onedrive, upload

I uploaded around 3K photos last night (~4GB) and in the morning I saw there was one photo left and it was stuck for a long time.
I decided to refresh the page (and cancel the upload by doing that), and uploaded the last file again.

Then, I noticed that the new folder has what I think to be a loading icon near it, and also its sub-folders and files has this icon near their name.

**What does it mean, and what should I do about it?**

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - it's not loading, it's **New**.

When hovering the little icon it says **Recently added**, and the html matches.

[image]